# Error fetching related entities with breezejs and web api2

Tags: breeze

We have just upgraded Breezejs to latest version(1.4.5) so that we can use it with EF 6. We also updated the project to Web Api2 with OData support.

In our code we fetch a entity with related entities by using expand on our query(from our datacontext.js):

```
BandContext.prototype.getBandWithDetails = function (bandId) {
        var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("Band").where(new breeze.Predicate("Id", "==", bandId)).expand("BandMembers.User.Image, BandImages.Image, Image, BandFollowers, ExternalLinks");
        return this.executeQuery(query);
    };
```

In breezecontroller.cs our action looks like this:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Queryable(AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.Supported | AllowedQueryOptions.Expand, MaxExpansionDepth = 4)]
    public IQueryable<Band> Band()
    {
        return WebRepository.Bands;
    }
```

This worked great for a long time, but have now stopped working. I still get a 200 when I call the WebApi controller and the entity and the related entities is sent over the wire, but I get this error message:

```
relatedEntity.getProperty is not a function
```

We totally clueless on what to do and any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Usually when I get this error it is because I am trying to do something against a property that either isn't coming back or is not a valid property on a navigation entity.  Are you sure these are valid properties of a band? BandMembers.User.Image, BandImages.Image, Image, BandFollowers, ExternalLinks

Comment: I get the same error when I try to call only expand('BandFollowers') or expand('Image') as well, and I know that thoose are valid.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually caused by an incomplete migration of your EF model to WebApi2.  My guess is that an error is being thrown on your server. Try debugging into the server side code.

Another customer ran into this and commented:

> "I found the problem, I debugged the function that fetches the metadata, and I found some client side entities that were defined with associations pointing to the old Entity Framework 5 namespaces."

Comment: Thanks for the fast respons, I've tried now, but still no luck. I've dived deeper into the error and this is what I got:
`TypeError: relatedEntity.getProperty is not a function:14223`
this happens on:
`updateRelatedEntityInCollection()`

Comment: Looking closer I see that I get the related entities with their properties, but without the extra properties and functions that breeze hooks on to them. The exception occurs:
`if (!relatedEntity) return;`
`var thisEntity = relatedEntity.getProperty(inverseProperty.name);`

@Jay

Comment: After backtracking the code and trying to figure out what went wrong, we runned a diff on a working verison and the faulty version. The only difference was
`public IQueryable<Band> Bands()`
instead of `public IQueryable<Band> Band()`
and `.from("Bands")`
instead of `.from("Band")`
When we changed back to Bands everything worked again, why it works is beyond me? @Jay

Comment: There are two concepts here. One is the name of your entityType, probably "Band", and the other is the name of the resource that you are querying, probably "Bands". The entityType name is what is returned by EF and is available in the metadataStore.  The resource name is the endpoint in your WebApi controller. More info here: http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/creating-entities

Answer (score 0):

In case this is not solved yet, I had problems with related entities not being loaded either when using `.Expand(...)` on the client. They would get send over the wire but the resulting object in Javascript did not contain them.

In the end I found I had to add explicit foreign keys to my (code first) entities.

### This did not work

```
public class MainItem
{
    public MainItem()
    {
        this.RelatedItems = new HashSet<RelatedItem>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<RelatedItem> RelatedItems { get; set; }
}
public class RelatedItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public MainItem MainItem { get; set; }
}
```

### But this worked

```
public class RelatedItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public MainItem MainItem { get; set; }
    public int MainItemId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Notice the extra property `MainItemId`, which suddenly made the related entities show up in the Javascript query result.